# How to use a field name as an argument for a nested select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to do something wonky, but I cant think of any other way to do it:

```
SELECT
    my_table.field1 as field1,
    (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM another_table WHERE id = field1)) as does_exist
FROM my_table
```

This obviously fails because `field1` doesn't exist at the time the result set is created. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Assuming `mytable.field1` doesn’t actually have the same name as `field1`, `id = mytable.field1`?

Comment: wow, this worked.

Comment: Accomplish what? All you've shown is code that doesn't work the way you unexplainedly expect it to which is some way other than it is supposed to work. What does "fails" mean? And don't rely too much on your guesses at "because".

Answer (score 2):

You can use left join:

```
select distinct on (t1.field1) t1.field1, t2.id is not null as does_exist
from my_table t1
left join another_table t2 on t2.id = t1.field1
```

however your query should work as well:

```
SELECT
    my_table.field1 as field1,
    (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM another_table WHERE id = my_table.field1)) as does_exist
FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
    my_table.field1 as field1,
    case another_table.ID
      when null then 0
      else 1
    end does_exist
FROM my_table
     left outer join another_table on another_table.ID = my_table.field1

Here 1 is Exists, and 0 not exists